# SQL - Extract latest transaction dates from a table grouped by asset (MS-ACCESS 2010)

Tags: sql, ms-access, maxdate, expressionbuilder

I am building a query to display the most current transactions (date) from a transaction table which are grouped by "Asset" (column B) so I can assign a current status to the asset.

Table example
TranX ID | Asset | Date Out   | Date In    |
001      | 1001  | 20-01-2023 | 31-02-2023 |
002      | 1001  | 03-03-2023 | 12-04-2023 |
003      | 1002  | 06-03-2023 | 13-04-2023 |
004      | 1002  | 18-04-2023 | 12-12-2023 |
005      | 1002  | 01-02-2024 |            |
etc

Query would display
002      | 1001  | 03-03-2023 | 12-04-2023 | Available
005      | 1002  | 01-02-2024 |            | In Use

I have a query created to display the transactions

SELECT Transactions.ID, Transactions.Asset, Transactions.[Checked Out To], Transactions.[Checked Out Date], Transactions.[Checked in Date], [Contacts Extended].[Contact Name], Transactions.Notes
FROM Transactions INNER JOIN [Contacts Extended] ON Transactions.[Checked Out To] = [Contacts Extended].ID;

I have tried to use the following SQL code to attempt what I am looking for

SELECT Transactions.ID, Transactions.Asset, Transactions.[Checked Out To], Transactions.[Checked Out Date], Transactions.[Checked in Date], [Contacts Extended].[Contact Name]
FROM  Transactions inner join (select asset, max([Checked Out Date]) as MaxDate from Transactions group by asset) tm on Transactions.[Asset] = tm.Asset and t.[Checked Out Date] = tm.MaxDate

But I am not very knowledgeable on SQL Expression building / editing and this code only works on one date column

Any help appreciated and I will apply learning to all answers.

Comment: You are using a table for which you haven't given us any details - this makes it harder for us to help you. Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

First you make an assumption that the date ranges have been recorded reliably and don't overlap.   If not, you'll have to think about cleaning that up first.

Then you create a subquery in the Where clause to bring back only the latest Date Out record and code an Iif() function to present status:

```
Select *, Iif("Date In" is null,'In Use','Available') as Status
from TranX O
Where "Date Out"=(
    Select max("Date Out") From TranX I
    Where O.Asset=I.Asset
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Just for my understanding, what function does Tranx O and TranX I perform?

Comment: The "I" & the "O" are table aliases, which are necessary because TranX is referenced twice and the "I" and the "O" make them unambiguous.  You say Where I.Asset=O.Asset to mean the inner query asset field must equal the outer query asset value.  That kind of constraint makes inner query into what is called a "correlated subquery".